# Entitlements file for Passbook

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, entitlements, passbook

Im trying to list installed passes in my app. I can add passes fine, but trying to list the passes I dont get any back in `[passLig passes];` on the device. Strange thing is that I do get them in the simulator..

Im thinking this got to do with the entitlements file. How should the entilements file look like if my passtypeid is "pass.myapp.boardingpass"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was solved by creating a NEW provisioning profile AFTER enabling passes on our APPID. Just using the old one we had before did not work, we had to use a new one for test. After installing that and restaring xcode we were able to get this part to work.

[image]